# How to use if else in this action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

How do you write an if/else statement for this method if there is no result?

```
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
    Helpers Helpers = new Helpers();
    var restaurants = Helpers.getRestaurant(q);

    return View("_RestaurantSearchResults", restaurants);
}
```

Helpers class contains:

```
public class Helpers
{
    FoodReviewContext _db = new FoodReviewContext();

    public static IQueryable<Restaurant> getRestaurant(string q)
    {
        var restaurents = _db.Restaurants
                        .Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(q) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
                        .Take(2);
        return restaurents;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are no results found, I'd defer to the view to be responsible to handling that circumstance. i.e. "No results found!" or the sort.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
    Helpers Helpers = new Helpers();
    var restaurants = Helpers.getRestaurant(q);
    if (restaurants.Count() == 0) { 
      // do something 
    } else {
      // do something else
    }        

    return View("_RestaurantSearchResults", restaurants);
}
```

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. This goes over all the methods in the `IQueryable<T>` interface.

Oftentimes when you are looking for how to work with a certain part of the .NET Framework, C#, or others' code, the documentation is the best first place to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (restaurants.Count() != 0)
{
//non-zero thing
}

else
{
//zero thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply check your result count for it.

```
 public ActionResult Search(string q)
 {
   Helpers Helpers = new Helpers();
   var restaurants = Helpers.getRestaurant(q);
   if(restaurants.Count()>0)
   {
     return View("_RestaurantSearchResults", restaurants);
   }
  else
  {
    ViewBag.Message="No result found";
    return View("_RestaurantSearchResults");
  }
 }
```

And just check if ViewBag.Message is available or not in View.

Comment: Hi manish, doesn't this mix the responsibilities of the controller and view?

Comment: Is there any other way to check at view side if no result?

Comment: Sure, just have the check and display in the view - really the only mixing responsibilities in your answer is the `ViewBag.Message="No result found";`